# Vuex getters get user role in component

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm new to dev with Vue.js Vuex and Firebase and I'm trying to show different navbar items based on user role.
I'm currently fetching user data from Firebase as an object and passing it to the store.

I tried to use getters in vuex to check user role and it's kind of working only if the user as the role 'admin'.

Here is my getters:

```
isAuthenticated (state) {
  return state.user
},
userAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'thinker'|| 'e-libre' || 'hacker' || 'admin',
reviewerAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'reviewer' || 'admin',
devAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'dev' || 'admin',
adminAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'admin',
```

I'm want these functions to return a boolean in computed property of my component so I can check whether the user is admin or for exemple reviewer so I can display different items.

Here is my computed function

```
computed: {
app$(): IApp {
  return this.$store.state;
},
isAuthenticated () {
  return this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated
},
adminAuth () {
  return this.$store.getters.adminAuth
},
reviewerAuth () {
  return this.$store.getters.reviewerAuth
},
```

and then I don't know why this function is working fine when the user role is 'admin' and not when the user as another role.

```
adminItems () {
    if (this.adminAuth) {
      return [
        { text: 'Admin', icon: 'lock', subheader: 'admin',
          children: [
            { text: 'Management', route: '/management', icon: ''},
            { text: 'Settings', route: '/settings', icon: ''}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

for exemple when the user as the role reviewer, reviewerAuth is returning undefined:

```
 <v-list-tile v-if="!adminAuth||!reviewerAuth" to="/" avatar>
          <v-list-tile-avatar>
          <v-icon>translate</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-avatar>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Devenir reviewer</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>

        </v-list-tile>
        <v-divider v-if="!adminAuth||!reviewerAuth"></v-divider>
        <v-list-tile
        v-for="(item, index) in userItems"
        :key="index"
        :to="item.path"
        avatar
        @click="">
        <v-list-tile-avatar>
        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-avatar>
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>

        </v-list-tile>
```

What am I missing there? I'm kinda learning javascript in the same time and feeling that I'm doing that completely wrong.

Thanks a lot for your help

Philmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple problem where the syntax of the checks is incorrect. Consider

```js
1 === 2 || 'hello'
```

This returns: `hello`.

Likewise you have a similar bug with:

```js
userAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'thinker'|| 'e-libre' || 'hacker' || 'admin',
reviewerAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'reviewer' || 'admin',
devAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'dev' || 'admin',
adminAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'admin',
```

Should be instead:

```js
userAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'thinker'|| state.user.roles === 'e-libre' || state.user.roles === 'hacker' || state.user.roles === 'admin',
reviewerAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'reviewer' || state.user.roles === 'admin',
devAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'dev' || state.user.roles === 'admin',
adminAuth: state => state.user.roles === 'admin',
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer